# Can I restrict my CRM Workflows to be executed by certain users

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to restrict my CRM Workflows to be executed by certain users.
I have tried making the scope of the workflow to 'user' level and sharing the workflow with the user.

Comment: This isn't possible since you cannot share workflows - you only can assign them.

Comment: FYI, I thought that this problem could be solved by adding plugin logic to the PreRetrieveMultiple operation on the workflow entity.  However it appears that the workflow entity does not support any plugins so this seems to be a dead end.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, but the logic must be built into the workflow code itself.

This will give you the GUID of the user who executed the workflow:

```
IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
var userId = context.InitiatingUserId;
```

From here you can stop/continue based on the user.

For a data-driven solution, you could build logic to only continue based on conditions; such as the user being assigned to a certain role.

**Edit** (based on my comment below)

Alternately, you can create a workflow which *returns* the executing user. This way you don't have to code the rules into the workflow source, rather you can add stop conditions in the workflow editor based on the return value of the "get executing user" workflow.

Someone has already written the code to do this: http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/10/get-current-user-inside-workflow.html

Comment: You can write a custom workflow assembly to do what jason suggested, try to keep an external parameter to make it dynamic (so no more code is required if you need to modify the list of users), for example you can write the guids of the allowed users and check them against the guid of the current one.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for the reply. But with this approach, every time I want to add a user to be able to access the logic, I need to make changes in the code.
I want to avoid code changes.

Comment: @Vivek - You could create a workflow which _returns_ the executing user and then you have a generic solution which you can use in future WF rules. This way you can explicitly add/remove users in a stop condition. Looks like someone has already written the code for it actually: http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/10/get-current-user-inside-workflow.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also put the scope of the workflow to Business Unit or Parent: Child Business Units. However, this isn't likely a good reason to change how your organization is structured in CRM.

http://blog.profad.com/crm-3/defining-scope-using-workflows-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/

Comment: Actually you can use security roles to execute workflows at user, unit, deep and organization level. Vivek needs to execute that workflow to "certain" users, that means he needs a new field on User "Execute Workflow", "Yes or No" and ask for that field in his Workflow. I don't really like this solution but it is an approach.

Comment: @Zach, I said nothing about security roles. I was talking about the business units that the users belong to.

Comment: Sxntk, I agree that what you are saying is basically an alternative way to accomplish what Jason Faulkner suggests.  I don't understand how it has anything to do with security roles though.

Comment: And Sam I think I did respond too hastily here without taking the time to understand what you were trying to suggest.  I still don't think this is an answer per-se but it is good insight.  Removed my original comment.

Comment: @Zach, maybe you could remove the downvote as well :)

Comment: I would be happy to do that except that I am blocked from doing so. If you make an edit to your answer then I think I can change my vote?